# GWT Asynchronouscallback timeout issue: Always going in OnFailure()

Tags: json, gwt, asynchronous, rpc, gwt-rpc

I am new to GWT. I have written a piece of code which makes asynchronous calls to the server. The server side code is running fine as seen through the logs. But on the client side I am getting a failure message.

I am trying to load large amount of data from the server. It seems like the async call times out before the entire data is returned from the server. Is there a way I can increase the timeout of the call? or is there any other issue with my code?

```
    public MapDataServiceFacadeAsync getMapDataServiceInstance()
{
    if (mapDataService == null)
    {
        mapDataService = MapDataServiceFacade.Util.getInstance();
    }
    return mapDataService;

    public void setTreeInstance(final String productName, final Object invObject, final boolean isToLoadTickets, final SearchItem search)
{
    refreshSearch = search;
    this.inventoryMapPanel = (InventoryMapPanel) invObject;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    getMapDataServiceInstance().getProductTree(userProfile, isToLoadTickets, search, new AsyncCallback()
    {  
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
        {  
            CommonMapUI.loadLabel(false);
            Window.alert("Failed to Load Tree. Please try again");

        }

        public void onSuccess(Object result)
        {
            tmpData = (MapItem[]) ((HashMap) result).get("tree");

            if (tmpData == null && Count < 3)
            {
                Count++;
                setTreeInstance(productName, invObject, isToLoadTickets, search);
            }
            else
            {
                buildProductTree(result, invObject, isToLoadTickets);
            }
        }
        });
}
```

It is always throwing the error "Failed to load Tree" if I try and retrieve large amount of data. It works fine if small amount of data is to be loaded.

Interface:

```
 public interface MapDataServiceFacadeAsync  {

 public void getProductTree(CommonUserProfile user, boolean isToLoadTickets,SearchItem search, AsyncCallback asynCall);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add servlet mean server side code..and what is error?  sysout caught error and put error also.

Comment: can you post what is shown in StackTrace when you the Exception is Caught

Comment: There are no exceptions in the StackTrace. In the server side the code is running fine and it is returning what is expected. But before it can be displayed in the UI, GWT pops up a window "Failed To Load Tree".

Comment: The strange thing about it is it throws a pop up with the error only when the amount of data to be fetched from the back end is large. For small amount of data the code works as expected.